# Is there a efficient way how to write long texts of items in a table?

Tags: tables

I have the following code, which puts a list out of 3 Problems and their solutions:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Problem 1}: \\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .
\item \textbf{Solution 1}: \\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text (max. 1000mm). 
\item \textbf{Problem 2}: \\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\item \textbf{Solution 2}: \\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text.
\item \textbf{Problem 3}:\\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
\item \textbf{Solution 3}: \\
ext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text, Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text, Text Text.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I would like to put this into a table instead of two columns I tried the following table code:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
    \caption{Probleme und Lösungen \cite{Codeleser}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{} >{\bfseries}l|X @{}|}
    \toprule     
    \textbf{Problem} & \textbf{Solution}  \\ 
    \midrule  
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text (max. 1000mm).\\ 
    \midrule  
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .  & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .\newline Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .\\ 
    \midrule  
    AText Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\newline Text Text Text Text . & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text . \newline Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .\\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

After compiling the table code, I get the following table on the image:

[image: 1]

I would be thankful for evey suggestion to put out a better table.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Basically, you need two X columns instead of one l and one X.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Probleme und Lösungen \cite{Codeleser}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}r X X}
    \toprule     
    & \textbf{Problem} & \textbf{Solution}  \\ 
    \midrule  
    1. &Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text (max. 1000mm). & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\ 
    \addlinespace  
    2. &Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .  & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .\\ 
    \addlinespace  
    3. & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text . & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: @leandris, but they are not aligned? For every problem should be a solution written on the right.

Comment: @ramles: I updated my anser accordingly.